# my washing machine was automatically stop and this message was shown

Tags: washing-machine

[image][image] 
 Samsung washing machine was automatically stopped and not working any botton exept power botton what should i do give any suggestions

Answer (score 2):

It means the door is not safely closed and latched.

Insure that the door is fully closed. Check for fabric and other obstructions. When the door is closed, the latch on the door pushes into the door interlock and slides a bar over. It should latch firmly and activate an electric switch inside the lock.

Insure that the machine is properly leveled and does not rock on two diagonally opposed feet. This can twist the frame and prevent the door from seating properly.

Check the child safety interlock if your machine has this feature. See the instruction guide for your model.